Help Installing Font in TeXShop on a Mac
I would like to know how to find, install, and use fonts for my mac system.  In particular, I would like to install Garamondx.  (I recently posted elsewhere about this, so hoping for more input and help.) Here are some relevant facts:
(1) I use MacOS Sanoma version 14.4.1 and
(2) TeXShop version Version 5.36 (5.36) (Compiling/Typesetting using LaTeX)
I am currently using Garamond EB and would like to switch to Garamondx.  Here is my code thing:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\geometry{margin=1.5in,top=1.5in}
\title{{\large{}}}

\date{}
\author{\normalsize{}}
\singlespacing

\usepackage[letterspace=150]{microtype}
\usepackage[md]{titlesec}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}

I am a complete novice at LaTeX so a more detailed step by step explanation would be better.  Thanks in advance.

please edit your question rather than asking a duplicate. this is the same question, but, if it was a followup, you should link to the earlier one.
